# Trying to clean up code and add 2 features

Tags: javascript, css, element

Here is a default setup of my page below

first question, is there a cleaner way of doing what my javascript is doing, meaning can the code be cleaned up and minimized or is it best the way its wrote.

second question, the right sidebar opens and closes like i want it to, but what is the best method (examples are gratefully appreciated) to close the right sidebar when someone clicks outside of it, but if there are clicks inside then it stays open for the user to interact with it, but then have it close only when a user has clicked an option inside, last thing is to still give the button labeled "right sidebar" the ability to close the sidebar.

thank you for any responses :)

```js
var lsidebtn = document.getElementById("sidebtnL");
      const sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar");
      const content = document.getElementById("content");
      lsidebtn.classList.add("active");
      function toggleSidebar() {
        if (!lsidebtn.classList.contains("active")) {
          lsidebtn.classList.add("active");
          sidebar.style.width = "280px";
          content.style.marginLeft = "280px";
        } else {
          lsidebtn.classList.remove("active");
          sidebar.style.width = "65px";
          content.style.marginLeft = "65px";
        }
      }

      var rsidebtn = document.getElementById("sidebtnR");
      const settingsbar = document.getElementById("settingsbar");
      function toggleSettingsbar() {
        if (!rsidebtn.classList.contains("active")) {
          rsidebtn.classList.add("active");
          settingsbar.style.right = "0px";
        } else {
          rsidebtn.classList.remove("active");
          settingsbar.style.right = "-260px";
        }
      }
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #333;
  color: white;
}

.header {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #141414;
  position: fixed;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 9;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.sidebar {
  background: #f00;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  width: 280px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.settingsbar {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  width: 260px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -260px;
  z-index: 20;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 25px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  margin-left: 280px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body class="">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="left">Left</div>
      <div class="center">
        <button type="button" class="" id="sidebtnL" onclick="toggleSidebar()">
          Left Sidebar
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          class=""
          id="sidebtnR"
          onclick="toggleSettingsbar()"
        >
          Right Sidebar
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="right">Right</div>
    </div>

    <div class="settingsbar" id="settingsbar">Settings</div>

    <div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
    <div class="content" id="content">
      <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum arcu
        nisl, luctus a maximus consectetur, convallis in elit. Cras at mi vitae
        augue elementum viverra nec ac est. In sodales turpis massa, eu faucibus
        est ultricies non. Praesent quis molestie felis, in convallis magna.
        Maecenas a pharetra eros. Ut vel molestie ligula. Nulla placerat lacinia
        diam nec vulputate. Sed ut lectus non felis lacinia hendrerit eu ut
        ligula. Vestibulum finibus dolor sit amet fringilla volutpat. Praesent
        quis sagittis diam, id egestas dolor. Fusce eu mi mattis, semper dolor
        sed, luctus erat. Cras et augue ultricies, pharetra odio eget, eleifend
        ligula. Morbi molestie et erat at commodo. Pellentesque ante enim,
        facilisis non tellus vitae, lacinia placerat lacus. Praesent iaculis
        purus eget ante eleifend, eget cursus quam egestas. Vestibulum sagittis
        tempor odio, vitae porttitor ex vehicula nec. Integer mi ex, varius
        facilisis lectus non, varius rhoncus urna. Proin fermentum felis
        sollicitudin sapien gravida interdum. Nulla suscipit, lorem at tincidunt
        pulvinar, neque turpis placerat nulla, vitae aliquet tortor lectus vel
        neque. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec posuere sapien vel nisl
        malesuada, quis mollis elit ultricies. Mauris suscipit libero dapibus,
        aliquet purus nec, commodo dui. Ut ultricies porta arcu quis finibus.
        Proin ante felis, sodales quis imperdiet eu, ornare a lorem. Donec
        scelerisque fermentum metus eu dictum. Proin quis laoreet urna. Cras
        quis ultricies arcu. Suspendisse lacinia erat leo, eu rhoncus lorem
        lacinia a. In malesuada porta urna, vestibulum eleifend justo gravida
        sed. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed
        consectetur nisl facilisis pretium auctor. Nunc porttitor, neque a
        rutrum pretium, erat augue venenatis nunc, ut elementum ligula risus et
        leo. Duis dictum auctor nulla, quis rhoncus nunc dapibus eget. Mauris
        bibendum enim ultricies massa mollis convallis. Curabitur egestas congue
        odio ultrices fringilla. Curabitur at sagittis lectus, at tempus augue.
        Ut bibendum, risus semper blandit tempus, lorem est ornare libero, vitae
        euismod velit orci vitae enim. Etiam sollicitudin sed est quis congue.
        Duis a convallis augue, eu facilisis felis. Nam consectetur luctus
        felis, sed pharetra arcu lobortis a. Etiam a ultrices purus. Sed felis
        leo, pretium eu orci at, vehicula rhoncus quam. Phasellus tincidunt odio
        vitae pretium tristique. Aliquam egestas vitae erat non varius. Mauris
        tincidunt tincidunt odio a dictum. Etiam lacus nibh, porta vel malesuada
        eu, ornare ac tortor. Morbi consequat eget risus vel posuere. In ac
        porttitor purus. Cras id nulla dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed id turpis mattis, vulputate felis sit
        amet, mollis magna. Mauris lobortis, urna a egestas lacinia, nunc risus
        blandit nibh, aliquet pharetra sem dolor ut nibh. Pellentesque sem
        lectus, laoreet mattis massa at, aliquet varius nisi. Nullam ullamcorper
        justo dui, quis sodales tellus consectetur vel. Proin dignissim tortor
        ac magna euismod, ut convallis nulla dapibus. Suspendisse in molestie
        diam. Morbi lobortis risus eget lectus sagittis dapibus. Sed bibendum in
        turpis sit amet accumsan. Suspendisse ut volutpat nibh, non imperdiet
        lorem. Donec pretium est vel vehicula fermentum. Cras at convallis est.
        Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere
        cubilia curae; Mauris faucibus maximus luctus. Proin lobortis nisl
        lorem. Quisque viverra vulputate magna, et viverra velit rutrum quis.
        Nulla molestie neque volutpat, varius nunc a, viverra lectus. Sed sed
        ultrices ligula, eu efficitur massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi
        tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla
        eu pellentesque nibh, sit amet mattis dolor. Nam dictum, nisl ac
        sagittis pretium, turpis nisi bibendum lorem, sit amet pellentesque
        ligula odio a metus. Praesent ornare scelerisque quam nec cursus.
        Phasellus vitae odio quam. Cras finibus sollicitudin erat at faucibus.
        Fusce vel nunc non lectus fermentum varius. Donec eget quam sit amet
        augue commodo pulvinar vel at sem. Donec vel felis consectetur, tempor
        sem ac, volutpat ex. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed hendrerit fringilla leo
        a eleifend. Donec tristique lacus euismod lorem congue, et dignissim
        odio finibus. Phasellus a dignissim magna. Sed congue mollis imperdiet.
        Praesent quis odio aliquet, tristique justo facilisis, imperdiet nisl.
        Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
        inceptos himenaeos. Morbi laoreet lacus in sapien molestie, at congue
        elit consequat. Suspendisse sit amet arcu quis nunc porta sollicitudin
        nec non mi. Integer commodo nisl ut urna venenatis, non vulputate diam
        euismod. Suspendisse tincidunt commodo lectus, eget placerat arcu
        placerat vel. Suspendisse tincidunt, arcu sit amet vestibulum dapibus,
        eros neque convallis ligula, sed vestibulum lorem eros a urna. Quisque
        non euismod odio. Mauris purus odio, venenatis ut nisl eget, venenatis
        interdum magna. Cras eu nisl nec lacus sodales accumsan eget eu metus.
        Ut laoreet posuere diam, et vestibulum mi cursus ornare. Vivamus feugiat
        luctus faucibus. Maecenas et tincidunt orci. Nam scelerisque ligula sit
        amet maximus sagittis. Pellentesque sodales ex a orci lobortis, a
        blandit lacus pellentesque. Nam interdum orci ut fermentum tempus. Fusce
        dolor tortor, consequat mollis leo vitae, molestie vestibulum mauris.
        Vivamus aliquet volutpat ultrices. Donec at arcu libero. Duis tincidunt
        consectetur semper. Quisque feugiat volutpat tortor eget iaculis.
        Quisque lobortis eros ut lectus luctus, a fermentum magna placerat. Ut
        id tortor pulvinar, euismod tellus eu, luctus sapien. Nam congue enim in
        nibh ullamcorper ultrices. Praesent consectetur, neque in blandit
        auctor, dolor magna porta nisl, a efficitur tortor neque sit amet massa.
        Aenean egestas ante justo, vel pharetra turpis dapibus ut. Suspendisse
        potenti. Ut placerat est ut sapien maximus, eu vulputate sapien congue.
        Duis porttitor nec lectus id mollis. Proin eu magna nec augue interdum
        tincidunt at eget lorem. Quisque tempor tincidunt tortor nec tempus.
        Morbi porta, orci id euismod laoreet, risus justo scelerisque arcu, quis
        egestas nisi lorem sit amet erat. Aliquam placerat ligula non lacinia
        bibendum. Nullam diam magna, condimentum id tincidunt ac, congue porta
        nisi. Duis posuere, neque id consectetur euismod, turpis eros suscipit
        nunc, eget dapibus justo lacus hendrerit nulla. Quisque vitae lectus sit
        amet velit pellentesque sollicitudin. Cras aliquam lorem euismod semper
        auctor. Cras pharetra nunc eu tristique hendrerit. Nunc efficitur a enim
        sit amet mattis. Nulla a hendrerit sem, viverra aliquet dolor. Quisque
        venenatis libero tortor, id interdum sem consectetur id. Donec quis
        fringilla lacus, interdum euismod lectus. Praesent porttitor, arcu sed
        efficitur commodo, ipsum nulla facilisis tortor, a volutpat orci turpis
        et neque. Nulla porta, nibh in bibendum gravida, eros arcu hendrerit
        nulla, nec finibus eros erat ac elit. Nullam ac elit vitae felis
        malesuada porta sed sed purus. Ut cursus ante ac fermentum faucibus.
        Etiam scelerisque neque eget lobortis dictum. Vestibulum nec ligula id
        elit malesuada tincidunt. In pretium, elit ut interdum fringilla, diam
        turpis volutpat odio, ut aliquet sem lorem vel ex. Fusce id cursus
        lectus, nec iaculis velit. Vestibulum sed lobortis nisl. Nunc cursus
        tristique odio at vulputate. Praesent vitae ligula eget mauris dignissim
        convallis vitae commodo massa. Phasellus volutpat sapien eu metus
        laoreet elementum. Nulla facilisi. Sed dignissim orci eget nisi cursus
        imperdiet. Donec vel accumsan diam. Fusce dictum quis est eget ultrices.
        Etiam aliquet hendrerit pharetra. Fusce libero mauris, efficitur id
        felis vel, hendrerit porttitor velit. Donec pretium malesuada mi et
        fermentum. Phasellus sed tempor odio, vehicula vulputate quam. Praesent
        et ex eu libero efficitur aliquet. Maecenas eget fringilla lorem.
        Curabitur quis elit consequat, mollis tortor nec, bibendum dolor.
        Vivamus magna enim, aliquam sit amet orci in, efficitur condimentum
        libero. Praesent aliquam euismod nibh. Vestibulum ornare velit et
        feugiat mollis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per
        conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed a efficitur massa. Nam erat
        neque, cursus in iaculis eu, dapibus blandit mauris. Maecenas eget justo
        justo. Donec euismod, libero non aliquet luctus, orci leo tristique
        ipsum, nec tincidunt nunc velit eget lacus. Vestibulum at venenatis
        diam, eu ultrices ipsum. Donec elementum tellus id arcu facilisis, et
        finibus ligula tempor. Quisque iaculis congue commodo. Etiam cursus
        justo arcu, non malesuada leo finibus at. Nullam auctor sem eu neque
        facilisis vestibulum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
        elit.
      </div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**lsidebtn   sidebtnL**

You should not use Variable Like That . It is not clean to Read for Your Team .
Example , If contents are like Settings  ,  I will use

```
const settingDrawer or const settingSidebar
```

(var is not use anymore in js world because of it can re declare and can access outside the block)

You can use Camel Case like that . If you want to learn more , visit [here](https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/clean-code-javascript#variables)

Try Javascript frontend library or framework like React If you want more cleaner Code and Advanced Features .
**But Step by Step is Good.**

Here is how you can clean code

```js
const sidebtnL = document.getElementById("sidebtnL");
const sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar");
const content = document.getElementById("content");
sidebtnL.classList.add("active");
function toggleSidebar() {
  const w = !sidebtnL.classList.contains("active") ? "280px" : "65px";
  sidebtnL.classList.toggle("active");
  sidebar.style.width = w;
  content.style.marginLeft = w;
}

const sidebtnR = document.getElementById("sidebtnR");
const settingsbar = document.getElementById("settingsbar");
function toggleSettingsbar() {
  const r = !sidebtnR.classList.contains("active") ? "0px" : "-260px";
  sidebtnR.classList.toggle("active");
  settingsbar.style.right = r;
}
```

1. Used the ternary operator ? to make the toggleSidebar and
   toggleSettingsbar functions shorter and more concise.
2. Used classList.toggle instead of classList.add and classList.remove
   to toggle the "active" class in the toggleSidebar and
   toggleSettingsbar functions.

Comment: sounds crazy but i actually know react better than pure vanilla javascript, i know react is javascript but its the syntax and way you put components together if you know what i mean :) im using pure javascript as im building a site in php to use a mysqli db on a shared host, i know you can use react with mysqli but there is more to that side of things. So how would i integrate what i asked in my 2nd question to the cleaned up code

Comment: you can use id for that .      document.onclick = funciton(e){ if(e.target.id !== sidebar){ sidebtnL.classList.remove("active");}           it will close when you click outside

Comment: ok its not the left sidebar i want to close when clicked outside its the right sidebar, i did state that in my question at the beginning, i appreciate the help and responses

Comment: i used your document.onclick function after the 2 sidebar functions but didnt work i know im missing something simple with the code or placement

Comment: You can log the event to see  , what element are clicking or onclick function is work or not .      document.onclick = function(e){console.log(e)}

Answer (score 0):

**Question 2**

We add click event for whole document and check element with id that we don't want to click . If element is outside of our target element . Call the close function.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  const target = event.target;
  if (
    target.id !== "sidebtnR" &&
    !target.classList.contains("settingsbar") &&
    settingsbar.classList.contains("active")
  ) {
    toggleSettingsbar();
  }
});
```

Comment: ok what am i doing wrong i added that code after the 2 functions and it still isnt closing, it opens and closes on the button with no problem but will not close when clicking outside of that right sidebar

Comment: So i added this to see what response i would get 

`if (target.id !== "sidebtnR" && !target.classList.contains("settingsbar") && settingsbar.classList.contains("active")) { toggleSettingsbar(); } else { console.log("Error " + target); }`

response -> 
[object HTMLButtonElement]

Comment: adjust the if condition and function call example . instead of toggling , just remove class  .        Tutorial in youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iP63fDXk-W8&t=105s

Comment: still nothing now it shows [object HTMLDivElement] in the console, i hope im allowed to do this but i have posted it on jsfiddle with everything you sent me so you can see its not doing what it should be, here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/nws9dgjq/

Comment: Now you can close by clicking outside . But there is some issues that you need to fix . It is button is not working . We need to click other place to open settingBar  instead of Open Button . Here is code sand box link https://codesandbox.io/s/late-dream-ltg43y?file=/script.js    I also added in css  for debuging  of button active state . Try to adjust the condition . Good Luck .

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i have worked it out and got it fixed here is what i changed to get it working

```
const sidebtnR = document.getElementById("sidebtnR");
  const settingsbar = document.getElementById("settingsbar");
  document.onclick = function(e) {
    if(e.target.id !== 'settingsbar' && e.target.id !== 'sidebtnR') {
      sidebtnR.classList.remove("active");
      settingsbar.classList.remove("active");
      settingsbar.style.right = "-260px"; **<-- added this line**
    }
  }
  function toggleSettingsbar() {
    const r = !sidebtnR.classList.contains("active") ? "0px" : "-260px";
    sidebtnR.classList.toggle("active");
    settingsbar.classList.toggle("active"); **<-- and this line**
    settingsbar.style.right = r;
  }
```